# Navigating from Github Repo to to the file location in our local system

Tags: git, github, localsystem

Suppose we have a created a Github repository, and the files are also locally available in my local system,

Now I want to directly navigate from Github Repo to the desired file location in my local system,

can we create a button or anything command in Github Repo or its README, that will directly navigate to the desired file location in local system.